# 404 when requesting jdbc-drivers.jar

Tags: sonarqube

After downloading & installing sonar (v3.6.2) I am getting the below error when running the analysis through maven (sonar:sonar)

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-        cli) on project bf-CompositeStub: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-    maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar failed: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.start()', instance 'org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector@134c5ff, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper: Cannot open connection to database: SQL driver not found org.h2.Driver -> [Help 1]

The access logs show that the problem is a 404 is being thrown when the jdbc drivers are requested.
I get the same error when directly trying to get the drivers through a remote browser (10.30.32.136:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar) 
or on the same box as the web server (curl localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar)

However I am able to browse the sonar site from a remote browser.

Here are the jetty access logs.

```
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:08:44:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:08:44:21 +0000] "GET /dependencies/index HTTP/1.1" 200 2159 "http://10.30.32.136:9000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:08:44:23 +0000] "GET /comparison/index HTTP/1.1" 200 4356 "http://10.30.32.136:9000/dependencies/index" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:08:44:24 +0000] "GET /dashboard/?did=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 3336 "http://10.30.32.136:9000/comparison/index" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:08:45:12 +0000] "GET /deploy/jdbc-driver.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1034 "-" "Java/1.6.0_29"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:09:30:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:09:30:11 +0000] "GET /deploy/jdbc-driver.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1034 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
10.30.32.29 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:09:30:11 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1034 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [30/Jul/2013:09:31:25 +0000] "GET /deploy/jdbc-driver.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1034 "-" "curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5"
```

I have tried changing the context root & using a mysql instance by changing properties in the sonar.properties file and reinstalling sonar completely but get the same issue each time.

Comment: Version 3.6.3 does not exist: can you update the ticket with the correct version of Sonar please?

Comment: Update to correct version 3.6.2